# Не работает переключение вкладок подгруженных через Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ест скрипт табов самый простой

Код tabs.js:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').delegate('li:not(.current)', 'click', function() {
      $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current').parents('div.section').find('div.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150);
    })
  })
})(jQuery)
```

Код html:

```
<div class="section">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="action-tab current">Вкладка 1</li>
    <li class="action-tab">Вкладка 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="box visible">контент 1</div>
  <div class="box">контент 2</div>
</div>
```

Есть поиск, в котором есть разделения на сущности (контакты, сделки, задачи) эти сущности я распихиваю по вкладкам. Сам поиск подгружает структуру вкладок и рассортированными сущности по вкладкам.

**Проблема в том-что в подгруженной структуре вкладок переключение не работает.** Каждый раз с поиском подгружать скрипт не выход да и не удобно, хотел обернуть сам скрипт переключения вкладок в функцию и потом при загрузке данных вызывать ее заново, не вышло...

**Как исправить JS чтобы работало?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отбой решил сам.

Поставил у табов класс `.action-tab` и поставил `$(document).on('click', '.action-tab', function() {...});`

код html

Ест скрипт табов самый простой

Код tabs.js:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '.action-tab:not(.current)',  function() {
            $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
                .parents('div.section').find('div.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150);

        })
    })
})(jQuery)
```

Код html:

```
<div class="section">
  <ul class="tabs">
     <li class="action-tab current">Вкладка 1</li>
     <li class="action-tab">Вкладка 2</li>                                   
  </ul>
  <div class="box visible">
     контент 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    контент 2
  </div>
</div>
```